# Possible for Google Bot to Execute PHP Script

Tags: php, cron, googlebot

I have a CRON job php script that I just set up not too long ago.  However, I noticed that the PHP file executed (without the cron job activating).  It appears that it happened when a Google Bot crawled the file, because I noticed that the following engine visited my page:

http://www.google.com/bot.html

My question is:

1) Is it possible, that by crawling my webpage, it could have executed the script?

2) How can I "hide" the CRON file from Google?

3) Would it be smart to place this file in somewhere other than my public_html directory?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) of course it is

2) see robots.txt (http://www.searchtools.com/robots/robots-txt.html)

3) yes. but if for some reason you depend on calling it via a http daemon you can use a little trick.

eg. first line of code:

```
if(!isset($_GET['execute'])
 exit;
```

in your crontab:

http://server.tld/file.php?execute=1

Answer (score 1):

1) If the file is placed in a public web directory, then yes, it could be executed by Googlebot (or any other visitor)

2) You could add a Disallow clause for it in your [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/). Any regular user can still go and execute it by visiting if you do this.

3) Yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use also php-cli. Define if it is cron job:

```
define('_DOING_CRON_', true);
```

Then in php file:

```
if(_DOING_CRON_ && php_sapi_name() != 'cli'){
    die("You cannot get here: this is only cron task.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Runifus' answer above solved it for me, however the Cron job command line does not work with the ? in the url to pass the querystring as I learnt here: [Cron Jobs calling a PHP script with variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872679/cron-jobs-calling-a-php-script-with-variables)

It should be like so:

```
http://server.tld/file.php execute=1
```

also the php condition is missing a closing parenthesis

```
if(!isset($_GET['execute']))  exit;
```