# Cron Jobs calling a PHP script with variables

Tags: php, cron

Is it correct to use the following command in a cron job:

> /usr/bin/php -q /home/******/public_html/scores.php?date=12/05/2009

I haven't found any supportive article / material to answer it, hence i am putting forth this question to the community.

So the question is is there a way for me to include a variable in a cron job calling a PHP script?

Thanks

Answer (score 38):

in cron jobs, here is how you should pass the argument

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/**/public_html/scores.php date=12/05/2009
```

*take note there is no "?"

Answer (score 17):

Nick, take a gander at http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php.

What you want to do is pass arguments in in the form of `php -f scores.php '12/05/2009'`.  At that point, you'll just look at the `$_SERVER['argv']` to get the value.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a cronjob to fetch it from your server:

```
wget -q -O /dev/null "http://yourdomain.com/scores.php?date=12%2F05%2F2009"
```

Comment: Sorry I am fairly inexperienced when it comes to cronjobs.  Are you saying that the line above would be in place on my command in the original post?

Comment: Yes. Eg. `0 * * * * wget -q -O /dev/null "http://yourdomain.com/scores.php?date=12%2F05%2F2009` would fetch the URL once an hour.

Comment: This seems like a cumbersome workaround when PHP already provides a method for passing in command-line arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, my quick workaround was to create a seperate file with the parameters declared inside it, and then 'include' the original Cron file.

i.e.:

```
$date = '12/05/2009';

include ('scores.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/**/public_html/scores.php 12/05/2009
```

Comment: What does this do differently and why is this better than @Dennis's answer

Comment: Sorry, but i don't have any idea. I just used it. Can you please explain this?