# Can I use GET with CRON in PHP

Tags: php, get, cron

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cron Jobs calling a PHP script with variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872679/cron-jobs-calling-a-php-script-with-variables)

I have a cron job set up and my command looks like this:

```
php -q home/seatbe5/public_html/shop/index.php?page=sendorder/sendorder
```

I get an error saying no input file specified?

When I remove the route=... it works fine.  is there a work around to this?

Thanks
Peter

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php

Comment: You could also try using this as your cron command (note there are no ? marks):

`/usr/bin/php -q /home/seatbe5/public_html/shop/index.php page=sendorder/sendorder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're host doesn't allow wget.  Write this simple php script:

script.php:

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/?param=2&param2=sdf');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

Then just put script.php in your cron.

I'm not entirely sure what your cron needs to do, does it need to return anything? If it just has to call it, and you don't need any dynamic parameters, this would be fine.

Comment: You just used my mind, I used curl then read this post!  Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

if u want pass arrguments into cli look at:
[argv](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php)

or u can edit cron job `wget http://site.com`

Comment: `curl/telnet/etc` some package which can send request